# Spring Data JPA + Hibernate way to set transient field without hitting db for each entity, without loading onetomany collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have two entities, simplified for the case. The isActive field changes with current time so i did not want to store it in db.

**Condition of isactive:**

isActive = 1 if (current_timestamp between userstatus.datebegin and userstatus.dateend) else isActive = 0

**What I want:**

I want to **get a set of ALL users**, with their **isActive values set** without hitting to the db **for every user** and preferably; **without userStatus collection carried around**. Is there a way to satify this programmatically or jpa way? Or what is the best way to achieve this?

**User.java:**

```
@Entity
public class User {

  @Id
  private long id;

  @Transient
  private int isActive;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<UserStatus> userStatus = new HashSet<>();


}
```

**UserStatus.java:**

```
public class UserStatus {

  @Id
  private long id;

  @Column
  private Date dateBegin;

  @Column
  private Date dateEnd;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name= "user_tr_id_no")
  private UmutUser user;


}
```

**UserRepository.java:**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, long> {

  Set<User> findAllFetchWithIsActive();
}
```

**Ways I tried:**

*Way1: PostLoad
Problem: If I dont fetch userStatus, it hits the db for every user object.

*Way2: JPQL Query:
Problem: Couldnt find a query to set transient value except something suggested [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674033/set-transient-value-from-database-with-spring-data-jpa) here. The problem is it hits the db for every user object again.

*Way3: Eagerly fetch userStatus, calculate isActive values in service, hide the set of userstatus in a DTO before passing around.
Problem: This is my last resort, I have doubts fetching userStatus set for ALL users is a good approach.

Comment: But you have a set of userStatus, then isActive if at least one accomplish your date range conditions?

Comment: How can I give those date range conditions then?

Comment: Your conditions are that if at least one UserStatus accomplish the range dates then the user is active, or must to be all userStatus?

Comment: @cralfaro Only one is enough

Comment: I'd do it with Case statement and a Native SQL. Select CASE WHEN getDate() between userStatus.startDate and userStatus.endDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 as is active ...... Doing this way, you can get all that you want in a single shot and you would be doing the processing where the data is.. And of course.. the SQL case statement implementation differs with vendors, what's your database ?

Comment: @Shriram I am using Oracle. I tried the case statement with JPQL but it gave me an object collection so p.isActive was still not set. I did not try native sql though.

Comment: It won't be set because, you have annotated @Transient to isActive, JPA will ignore such fields. Take that off and use native SQL and use EntityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, User.class) when you're creating JPA query. Let me know if you still face issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM User u WHERE u.userStatus.dateBegin < CURRENT_DATE AND u.userStatus.dateEnd > CURRENT_DATE")
Iterable<User> findAllActiveUsers();
```

And in your User class

```
@Entity
public class User {

  @Id
  private long id;


  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<UserStatus> userStatus = new HashSet<>();

  @Transient   
  public int isActive(){
      for(UserStatus status: userStatus) {
           //Add your logic to check if the current date is between the range
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: This gets me only the active users. I need to get ALL of the users, and somehow mark them active or not. Without making redundant queries and considering performance.

Comment: @Oks, then ignore the repository method but keep in mind the second method isActive(), but for every time you use the method isActive() then will hit the DB to fetch the userStatus list. There are not any magic to do what you want. Depends of what you need for your business logic is better do 2 queries, 1 for recover all users and other only the actives, this would improve performance probably, but again, depends on your business logic

Comment: thanks, i think it is fine to use 2 queries like that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `new` operator:

```
select new UserWithStatus(
  u, 
  u.userStatus.dateBegin < CURRENT_DATE AND u.userStatus.dateEnd > CURRENT_DATE)
from User u
```

And have your object `UserWithStatus`:

```
public class UserWithStatus {
  private User user;
  private boolean active;
  public UserWithStatus(User user, boolean active) {
    this.user = user;
    this.active = active;
  }
}
```

And have this in your repository:

```
@Query("...")
Set<UserWithStatus> findAllFetchWithIsActive();
```

**Note:** I think this will bring you duplicate (eg: one User with several status). You might need to use a subquery and I don't know if JPQL will allow you this:

```
select new UserWithStatus(u, 
           (select count(*) 
            from u.userStatus w 
            where w.dateBegin < CURRENT_DATE 
              and w.dateEnd > CURRENT_DATE)) > 0
from User u
```

Comment: That query still hits the db for N+1 times for me.